# Zero Inflated Poisson Regression in R

Tags: r, model, poisson-regression, zero-inflation

I have a zero inflated Poisson regression model I want to run R, as my data are over-dispersed and I have many zeros, but I am not sure how to set up the model in R and interpret the output. First, is there a method I should be using to select variables to be modeled as count or binary, or run do I run them all as both? I know the default in R is that all of the variables are included as count and binary, but I'm not sure if I should be selecting specific variables. So for example, running:

`model1 <- zeroinfl(outcome ~var1 +var2 +var3 | var1+var2, data =dataset)`

Then for the output, do I interpret only the count versions of variables included as both binary and count... or do you have to report both?
If anyone has an example of a table or anything, that would be so helpful, I'm not finding any...

Comment: which package are you using here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cannot be answered without answers to follow-up, and the OP hasn't been seen for ages